# Visual Studio 2015 local help doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to install C help on my local computer. I have successfully done that with all previous versions of VS. But with VS 2015 it does not seem to work. I have searched for help on this issue but to no avail.

Here is what I do (note there is no separate option for C so I am selecting C++):

```
-press ctrl/alt/F1
-under Installation source select Online
-fill in the Local store path
-click on Add for Visual C++, .NET framework and Fundamentals
-click update
```

Then I go to my source code and press on a function (in this case fprintf and strtok). But it always uses microsoft.com.

Does anyone know what may be going on?

Comment: Have you tried Help -> Set Help Preference -> Launch in Help Viewer? This will stop it from opening help in a browser if that's what you're experiencing

Comment: Perfect! I don't remember having to do that in the past. Please add your comment as an answer. I will vote it up.

Comment: Glad I could help! My VS2013 also seems to go to microsoft.com.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `Help -> Set Help Preference -> Launch in Help Viewer`? This will stop it from opening help in a browser if that's what you're experiencing

Comment: Perfect. I would give you up votes but I don't have enough points yet.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer by clicking the tick icon